# Adding one element to recyclerview is adding entire arrayList again

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have an recyclerView which is working fine.
Now if I append an element in the recyclerView and call notifyDataSetChanged() method, it is appending the entire recyclerView with it along with 2 extra copies of the last added item.

Main class

```
imageList.add(value);
galleryAdapter.addElement(value);
```

Here imageList is an arrayList of strings and value is a string.

AdapterClass for the recyclerView

`public void addElement(String list){
        images.add(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

I have checked and made sure the data is working fine. If I leave the screen and open it again, it shows properly with the added element at correct position.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Main class

```
imageList.add(value);
galleryAdapter.addElement(imageList);
```

Adapter

```
public void addElement(yourlist list){
        images.add(list);
       notifyItemRangeChanged(0,list.size()-1);
    }
```

hope it will help you.

Comment: Still I am getting the same result

Comment: Both the codes are correct. The arrayList I was passing had the issue since I was changing the activity. It calls onCreate also other than onActivityResult